# Event delegation not working correctly with if else statement

Tags: javascript

I have assigned an event listener to a HTML container and when the user clicks on the play again button, the code within the 'if' statement should execute. Nothing is happening when clicking on the play again button and nothing is being logged to the console. I have tried various different ways of doing it such as testing to see whether the element has a certain class name etc.

Here is the relevant HTML code:

```
<div class="play-again-btn">
 <input type="button" class="play-btn" value="PLAY AGAIN">
</div>
```

Here is where the event listener is assigned to the container:

```
document.querySelector(DOMstrings.endContainer).addEventListener("click", playerCtrl.playAgain);
```

Here is the playAgain method:

```
playAgain: (event) => {
            let finishedPlayer, parentEl;

            console.log(event.target);

            //1. only action below code if correct button is clicked (correct target element is clicked) 
            if (event.target.nodeName == "input") {

                //2. delete existing character from finish line
                finishedPlayer = document.querySelector(DOMstrings.finishBox);
                finishedPlayer.removeChild(finishedPlayer.childNodes[0]);

                //3. bring character select pop up

                document.querySelector(DOMstrings.usersInput).style.visibility = "unset";


                //4. remove leaderboard pop up 

                parentEl = document.querySelector(DOMstrings.endContainer);
                parentEl.removeChild(parentEl.childNodes[1]);
            }

          },
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`Node#nodeName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeName) property stores the type of the node (`Text`, `Element`, `Comment`, etc.) not the tag name of the HTML element represented by the node.

So, `Node#nodeName` will never be equal to `"input"`, and your code won't run.

To check the tag name, use [`Element#tagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName) instead:

```
if (event.target.tagName == "input") {
```

Also, instead of that, it seems better to check if the clicked element *is* your button, so, if you can select the button, it's better to do an equality check with it:

```
if (event.target === document.querySelector(selectorOfButton)) {
```

Comment: Sorry I never responded to this, i've been away. Thank you for your response. Unfortunately neither of those suggestions worked, it still does nothing. It's not the end of the world as I have made some changes so that this is no longer necessary! Thanks again